# Flask - Get_JSON changing delimiter

Tags: python, json, flask

I post the following JSON to my flask server:

```
'{"on":false}'
```

I then use the following line of code to return the JSON to HTTP PUT it onto another device on the network:

```
content = ("'" + str(request.get_json()) + "'").lower()
```

However, instead of returning the expected:

```
'{"on":false}'
```

It returns:

```
'{'on':false}'
```

Thus meaning the JSON is invalid and does not work. Is there something I can change in the request.get_json() or is there a different method?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some strange things here.

`get_json()` automatically parses the incoming JSON string into a Python data structure. You then call `str` on it, converting it back not into JSON but into a representation of the Python structure.

Now, you *could* call `json.dumps` instead of `str`, but it would be better to avoid converting it from JSON in the first place. Instead of using `request.get_json`, use `request.get_data`; now Flask won't parse the content from JSON, and your quotes will be preserved.

Comment: My reason for turning it into a string is because I could not add the apostrophe delimiter on while it was a dict, and I was unsure for a workaround on for that.

Comment: You *don't need* to add any "apostrophe delimiter". I don't know why you think you do; that's just what marks it as a string. If you wrap it in a second set of quotes, it won't be valid JSON at the other end.

Comment: Ok, apologies. I see it works fine without. I am sorry.